# What's the relationship between environments and projects in virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

In other words, what's the difference between the `mkvirtualenv` and `mkproject` commands?

I have a workflow that looks like this:

```
/dev
    projectA
        appA
        appB
    projectB
        appA
        appB
```

All of the apps share some resources (like South, pep8, etc.), but other resources are specific to each app. Should I be using virtualenvwrapper "projects" to keep these dependencies separated?

Comment: What is a virtualenvwrapper project? Virtualenwrapper makes, manages, and deletes virtualenvs. You can make any virtualenv you like active for a terminal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From my understanding of the [documentation](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#project-directory-management), `mkvirtualenv projectenv` simply creates a new virtual environment named `projectenv` in `$WORKON_HOME`, while `mkproject projectenv` creates a new virtual environment named `projectenv` and a new directory named `projectenv`; after creation, the `projectenv` directory automatically becomes your current working directory. The virtual environment will exist in `$WORKON_HOME` and the development directory exists in `$PROJECT_HOME`.

Note, for`mkproject` to work correctly, you must first set the environment variable `PROJECT_HOME` to the name of the directory where you would like projects to be created. You can do this in the same place you set your `$WORKON_HOME` variable or set it up on the fly, e.g.

```
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/src/allprojects 
mkproject mynewproject
```

`mynewproject` will now be your current virtual environment and a new `mynewproject` directory will exist in `~/src/allprojects`.

Answer (score 4):

mkvirtualenv is command from virtualenvwrapper that makes managing python virtualenvs easier, while mkproject comes from a virtualenvwrapper plugin to manage your projects (that was integrated directly into virtualenvwrapper)

the plugin page mentions the following features:

> Manages your development project work directories along with your
>   virtualenv environments. Defines an API for creating templates to
>   quickly create new environments consistently. Use workon command from
>   virtualenvwrapper to switch between projects. User-configurable hooks
>   for customizing new projects.

You don't have to create or manage your projects using the virtualenvwrapper plugin to use the virtualenv commands. It's just a convenience plugin for stuff like swapping to the project directory when issuing a workon command, or from creating new projects from templates.

virtualenv for itself has no library sharing capability except with the systems site-packages if you use the correct flag. I stumbled once over a project that gave you this ability among other things, but never found it again.

EDIT: virtualenvwrapper now has the functionality to [copy virtualenvs](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#cdsitepackages), and to add directories to your virtualenv PATH in order to [share libraries](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv).