# Using mkproject in Python's virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to understand when is best to use `mkproject` vs `mkvirtualenv` when using `virtualenvwrapper`.

I found a couple of answers of what is the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811942/differentiate-mkvirtualenv-and-mkproject-for-virturalenvwrapper) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288297/whats-the-relationship-between-environments-and-projects-in-virtualenvwrapper/9425560).

From the second link, this seems to be the best summary of the differences:

> From my understanding of the documentation, `mkvirtualenv projectenv` simply creates a new virtual environment named `projectenv` in `$WORKON_HOME`, while `mkproject projectenv` creates a new virtual environment named `projectenv` and a new directory named `projectenv`; after creation, the `projectenv` directory automatically becomes your current working directory. The virtual environment will exist in `$WORKON_HOME` and the development directory exists in `$PROJECT_HOME`.

When would it be more appropriate to use `mkproject` and when `mkvirtualenv`? I would really find an example of the differences useful if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkvirtualenv` creates (and activates) just a virtualenv — a python environment that separates libraries from globally installed to prevent your development from messing with system libraries.

`mkproject` creates (and activates) a virtualenv and a new empty directory in which you will do your development.

If you already done some development and have a directory with source code you still can make it a project: create or activate a virtualenv, change directory to the source code directory and run `setvirtualenvproject`.

The only advantage of marking a source code directory being a project is that when you activate the environment `virtualenvwrapper` automatically change directory to the source code directory. And you can do it from the command line with command `cdproject`.